# How can I loop my java tax calculator so it restarts after throwing an exception?

Tags: java, loops, exception, java.util.scanner, calculator

Im doing a java course and Im stuck with an exercise. I created a tax calculator that applies different tax percentages over an user input amount of money, depending on the range that the amount of money is located in. The calculator works exactly as intended. I added a try/catch statement so in case someone inputs text instead of integer numbers it throws a NumberFormatException and prints a 'please introduce a valid number line'. I want my calculator to loop back to the first `System.out.println()` and restart the program when the NumberFormatException is triggered. I tried doing it with a do/while loop using booleans but I can't get it to work. Here's my calculator without loops:

```
public class Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Por favor introduce el importe de las ganancias en euros.");
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int minimumAmount = 0;
    int lowerLimit1 = 5000;
    int higherLimit1 = 25000;
    int lowerLimit2 = 25000;
    int higherLimit2 = 55000;
    int lowerLimit3 = 55000;
    int higherLimit3 = 200000;
    int lowerLimit4 = 200000;
    int higherLimit4 = 1000000;
    int gains = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

    try {
        if (gains > minimumAmount && gains < lowerLimit1) {
            System.out.println("Tus ganancias están libres de impuestos.");
        } else if (gains >= lowerLimit1 && gains < higherLimit1) {
            float taxes = 8F;
            System.out.println("Tus ganancias han sido de " + (gains - lowerLimit1) + " euros. Por tanto, con un " + taxes + "% de impuestos tendrás que pagar " + ((gains - lowerLimit1) * (taxes / 100)) + " euros.");
        } else if (gains >= lowerLimit2 && gains < higherLimit2) {
            float taxes = 10F;
            System.out.println("Tus ganancias han sido de " + (gains - lowerLimit2) + " euros. Por tanto, con un " + taxes + "% de impuestos tendrás que pagar " + ((gains - lowerLimit2) * (taxes / 100)) + " euros.");
        } else if (gains >= lowerLimit3 && gains < higherLimit3) {
            float taxes = 12F;
            System.out.println("Tus ganancias han sido de " + (gains - lowerLimit3) + " euros. Por tanto, con un " + taxes + "% de impuestos tendrás que pagar " + ((gains - lowerLimit3) * (taxes / 100)) + " euros.");
        } else if (gains >= lowerLimit4 && gains < higherLimit4) {
            float taxes = 15F;
            System.out.println("Tus ganancias han sido de " + (gains - lowerLimit4) + " euros. Por tanto, con un " + taxes + "% de impuestos tendrás que pagar " + ((gains - lowerLimit4) * (taxes / 100) + " euros."));
        } else if (gains > higherLimit4) {
            float taxes = 17F;
            System.out.println("Tus ganancias han sido de " + (gains - higherLimit4) + " euros. Por tanto, con un " + taxes + "% de impuestos tendrás que pagar " + ((gains - higherLimit4) * (taxes / 100) + " euros."));
        }


    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Por favor introduce un número válido.");
    }
}
```

And this is how I tried to loop it:

```
public class Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Por favor introduce el importe de las ganancias en euros.");
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int minimumAmount = 0;
    int lowerLimit1 = 5000;
    int higherLimit1 = 25000;
    int lowerLimit2 = 25000;
    int higherLimit2 = 55000;
    int lowerLimit3 = 55000;
    int higherLimit3 = 200000;
    int lowerLimit4 = 200000;
    int higherLimit4 = 1000000;
    int gains = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    boolean isValid = true;

    do {
        try {
            if (gains > minimumAmount && gains < lowerLimit1) {
                System.out.println("Tus ganancias están libres de impuestos.");
            } else if (gains >= lowerLimit1 && gains < higherLimit1) {
                float taxes = 8F;
                System.out.println("Tus ganancias han sido de " + (gains - lowerLimit1) + " euros. Por tanto, con un " + taxes + "% de impuestos tendrás que pagar " + ((gains - lowerLimit1) * (taxes / 100)) + " euros.");
            } else if (gains >= lowerLimit2 && gains < higherLimit2) {
                float taxes = 10F;
                System.out.println("Tus ganancias han sido de " + (gains - lowerLimit2) + " euros. Por tanto, con un " + taxes + "% de impuestos tendrás que pagar " + ((gains - lowerLimit2) * (taxes / 100)) + " euros.");
            } else if (gains >= lowerLimit3 && gains < higherLimit3) {
                float taxes = 12F;
                System.out.println("Tus ganancias han sido de " + (gains - lowerLimit3) + " euros. Por tanto, con un " + taxes + "% de impuestos tendrás que pagar " + ((gains - lowerLimit3) * (taxes / 100)) + " euros.");
            } else if (gains >= lowerLimit4 && gains < higherLimit4) {
                float taxes = 15F;
                System.out.println("Tus ganancias han sido de " + (gains - lowerLimit4) + " euros. Por tanto, con un " + taxes + "% de impuestos tendrás que pagar " + ((gains - lowerLimit4) * (taxes / 100) + " euros."));
            } else if (gains > higherLimit4) {
                float taxes = 17F;
                System.out.println("Tus ganancias han sido de " + (gains - higherLimit4) + " euros. Por tanto, con un " + taxes + "% de impuestos tendrás que pagar " + ((gains - higherLimit4) * (taxes / 100) + " euros."));
            }


        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Por favor introduce un número válido.");
            isValid = false;
        }
    } while (isValid != false);
}
```

With this loop the `try` part works perfectly but as soon as I input text console throws this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "text"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:660)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:778)
at Application.main(Application.java:209)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: move `int gains = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());` to try block

Comment: that doesnt throw the error but it ends the program @sanjeevRm

Comment: check updated answer, you can read `nextLong` from user input and avoid string to number conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this. Use `Scanner.nextInt()` and continue processing until you have valid input.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            boolean notValid = true;
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
            int minimumAmount = 0;
            int lowerLimit1 = 5000;
            int higherLimit1 = 25000;
            int lowerLimit2 = 25000;
            int higherLimit2 = 55000;
            int lowerLimit3 = 55000;
            int higherLimit3 = 200000;
            int lowerLimit4 = 200000;
            int higherLimit4 = 1000000;
            int gains = 0;
            while (notValid) {
               try {
                  System.out.println("Por favor introduce el importe de las ganancias en euros.");
                  gains = reader.nextInt();
                  notValid = false;
               }  catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                  System.out.println("Por favor introduce un número válido.");
                  reader.nextLine(); // clear input buffer
               }
            }
           
            // rest of your code (conditionals and output) goes here.
```

You could also replace you try/catch with the following:

```
while (notValid) {
    System.out.println("Por favor introduce el importe de las ganancias en euros.");
    if (reader.hasNextInt()) {
        gains = reader.nextInt();
        notValid = false;
    } else {
         System.out.println("Por favor introduce un número válido.");
        reader.nextLine(); // clear input buffer
    }
}
```

Comment: Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting NumberFormatException before try/catch , you need to move `int gains = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());` to try/catch block as below

```
do {
        try {
            int gains = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
            if (gains > minimumAmount && gains < lowerLimit1) {
                System.out.println("Tus ganancias están libres de impuestos.");
            } else if (gains >= lowerLimit1 && gains < higherLimit1) {
                float taxes = 8F;
                System.out.println("Tus ganancias han sido de " + (gains - lowerLimit1) + " euros. Por tanto, con un " + taxes + "% de impuestos tendrás que pagar " + ((gains - lowerLimit1) * (taxes / 100)) + " euros.");
            } else if (gains >= lowerLimit2 && gains < higherLimit2) {
                float taxes = 10F;
                System.out.println("Tus ganancias han sido de " + (gains - lowerLimit2) + " euros. Por tanto, con un " + taxes + "% de impuestos tendrás que pagar " + ((gains - lowerLimit2) * (taxes / 100)) + " euros.");
            } else if (gains >= lowerLimit3 && gains < higherLimit3) {
                float taxes = 12F;
                System.out.println("Tus ganancias han sido de " + (gains - lowerLimit3) + " euros. Por tanto, con un " + taxes + "% de impuestos tendrás que pagar " + ((gains - lowerLimit3) * (taxes / 100)) + " euros.");
            } else if (gains >= lowerLimit4 && gains < higherLimit4) {
                float taxes = 15F;
                System.out.println("Tus ganancias han sido de " + (gains - lowerLimit4) + " euros. Por tanto, con un " + taxes + "% de impuestos tendrás que pagar " + ((gains - lowerLimit4) * (taxes / 100) + " euros."));
            } else if (gains > higherLimit4) {
                float taxes = 17F;
                System.out.println("Tus ganancias han sido de " + (gains - higherLimit4) + " euros. Por tanto, con un " + taxes + "% de impuestos tendrás que pagar " + ((gains - higherLimit4) * (taxes / 100) + " euros."));
            }


        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Por favor introduce un número válido.");
            isValid = false;
        }
    } while (isValid != false);
```

**You can avoid this number format exception by changing this gains type as long and reading long from scanner**

```
do {
  ...
  long gains = reader.nextLong();
  ...
} while(reader.hasNextLong());
```

Comment: that works and lets you use the calculator as many times as you want if you input valid numbers, but if you input text or any other non valid characters the catch's `System.out.println()` gets executed and the program finishes with exit code 0. I would like it to restart the program when a non valid character is input

Comment: since you will not get NumberFormat exception after changing to nextLong, ,you need to move line setting isValid from catch block , instead check if `reader.hasNextLong()`